# Pass Block through multiple Templates

Tags: twig

I am trying to set up some common templates, that I want to use throughout my site.
Starting with a template in order to render Users. I have devided this into two different subtemplates:
users.html.twig (Template in order to show a table of Users)
user.html.twig (Template to render a single User)

Depending on the Controller this subtemplates are "included" I may want to add some buttons for each user.

Lets assume I have an action where I can search for users. This Action has the template search.html.twig
Now I want to include within my search.html.twig the users.html.twig which itself includes user.html.twig.  The tricky part is, I want to define in search.html.twig a single block that is rendered in user.html.twig. I tried it with embed, but unfortunately it renders nothing:

search.html.twig

```
{% embed 'StregoUserBundle:Entity:users.html.twig' with {'users': results, 'perRow' : 3} %}
            {% block user_additional %}
                    TOOOOOOOOOOOOP
            {% endblock user_additional %}
{% endembed %}
```

users.html.twig

```
{% block user_table %}
    {% for user in users %} 
        <div >
                {% embed 'StregoUserBundle:Entity:user.html.twig' with {'user': user} %}
                    {% block user_additional %}
                           {{ parent()}}
                    {% endblock user_additional %}
                {% endembed %}  
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock user_table %}
```

user.html.twig

```
{% block single_user %}
            <div class="people-list">
            <a href="{{ path('profile_show', { 'username': user.username }) }}">
                <img src="{{ user.profilePic  | imagine_filter('profile_thumb') }}" alt="{{ user.username }}" class="img-polaroid">
            </a>
            <a href="{{ path('profile_show', { 'username': user.username }) }}"><h3>{{ user.username }}</h3></a>
            <h3><small>{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</small></h3>
            {% block user_additional %}
            {% endblock user_additional %}

            </div> 

{% endblock single_user %}
```

I have tried several combinations of {{ block('XXX')}}, includes, embed, use etc... but did not find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Should't

```
{% endembed %}
```

be

```
   {% embeded %}
```